# Display dummy row as group by clause heading in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have 3 tables say company, department and employee. Now I want to find out all the employees who works in company A under department D and want to display data as below.

There is parent key relation between all this tables

```
**TABLE COMPANY**

  COMPANY_NAME  COMPANY ID
     C1            COMP1
     C2            COMP2
     C3            COMP3

 **TABLE DEPARTMENT**
 DEPARTMENT_NAME    COMPANY_NAME
   D1                C1
   D2                C1
   D3                C2

   **TABLE EMPLOYEE**
  EMPLOYEE_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME
   E1              D1
   E2              D1
   E3              D1
   E4              D2
   E5              D2

Company -- > Department --- > Employee.
```

I also want to display entity against each column as dummy column.

```
ENTITY     COMPANY_NAME DEPARTMENT_NAME EMPLOYEE_ID
COMPANY      C1           -              -
DEPARTMENT   C1           D1               
EMPLOYEE     C1           D1             E1
EMPLOYEE     C1           D1             E2
EMPLOYEE     C1           D1             E3
DEPARTMENT   C1           D2             -
EMPLOYEE     C1           D2             E4
EMPLOYEE     C1           D2             E5  ``
```

I Have tried this with group by, but with group by I get data as vertical tree like structure. but what i want is there should be heading like company or department and under that employees under that department should display. Is there are possible way we can do this in sql or plsql. ?

for left outer join

```
 ENTITY     COMPANY_NAME DEPARTMENT_NAME EMPLOYEE_ID
    COMPANY      C1           -              -
    DEPARTMENT   C1           D1               
    EMPLOYEE     C1           D1             E1
    EMPLOYEE     C1           D1             E2
    EMPLOYEE     C1           D1             E3
    DEPARTMENT   C1           D2             -
    EMPLOYEE     C1           D2             E4
    EMPLOYEE     C1           D2             E5 
    COMPANY      C2           -              -
    DEPARTMENT   C2           D3             -
    COMPANY      C3           -              -
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, as tabular text. You did not show which data you are starting from, only the results you want.

Comment: Added data for tables just for reference how data in actual tables would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do this using aggregation -- and `grouping sets`.  This looks like:

```
select (case when grouping(employee_id) = 0 then 'EMPLOYEE'
             when grouping(department_name) = 0 then 'DEPARTMENT'
             else 'COMPANY'
        end) as entity,
       company_name, department_name, e.employee_id
from company c join
     department d
     using (company_name) join
     employee e
     using (department_name)
group by grouping sets ( (company_name, department_name, e.employee_id), (company_name, department_name), (company_name) )
order by company_name, department_name nulls first, employee_id nulls first;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=acfd0a90cb8e256f2fa6ddf82caa97c0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I have one more requirement to show the department name and company name that is not part of employee table or company not part of department table, like we show using outer join, but when I try left join using this query I am getting 3 entries for outer join with emp table, whereas I think I should get only 2. and for company i should get only one. Can you please suggest to get output as shown under heading for outer join.

Comment: would you please help me with this.

Comment: @Pritesh . . . Please ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Added new question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981471/show-dummy-row-as-group-by-heading-for-left-outer-join

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` as follows:

```
SELECT COMPANY_NAME, NULL AS DEPARTMENT_NAME, NULL AS EMPLOYEE_ID 
  FROM COMPANY C 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEE E JOIN DEPARTMENT D USING (DEPARTMENT_NAME) 
                WHERE C.COMPANY_NAME = D.COMPANY_NAME)
UNION ALL
SELECT COMPANY_NAME, DEPARTMENT_NAME, NULL AS EMPLOYEE_ID 
  FROM COMAPNY C JOIN DEPARTMENT D USING (COMPANY_NAME)
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEE E 
                 WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_NAME = D.DEPARTMENT_NAME)
UNION ALL
SELECT COMPANY_NAME, DEPARTMENT_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID 
  FROM EMPLOYEE JOIN DEPARTMENT USING (DEPARTMENT_NAME)
ORDER BY COMPANY_NAME, 
         DEPARTMENT_NAME NULLS FIRST, 
         EMPLOYEE_ID NULLS FIRST;
```