# show dummy row as group by heading for left outer join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables say company, department and employee. Now I want to find out all the employees who works in company A under department D and want to display data for inner as well as left outer join to see any department that does not have any employee and company which does not have any department.

There is parent key relation between all this tables

```
**TABLE COMPANY**

  COMPANY_NAME  COMPANY ID
     C1            COMP1
     C2            COMP2
     C3            COMP3

 **TABLE DEPARTMENT**
 DEPARTMENT_NAME    COMPANY_NAME
   D1                C1
   D2                C1
   D3                C2

   **TABLE EMPLOYEE**
  EMPLOYEE_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME
   E1              D1
   E2              D1
   E3              D1
   E4              D2
   E5              D2

Company -- > Department --- > Employee.
```

I also want to display entity against each column as dummy column.

```
    ENTITY     COMPANY_NAME DEPARTMENT_NAME EMPLOYEE_ID
    COMPANY      C1           -              -
    DEPARTMENT   C1           D1               
    EMPLOYEE     C1           D1             E1
    EMPLOYEE     C1           D1             E2
    EMPLOYEE     C1           D1             E3
    DEPARTMENT   C1           D2             -
    EMPLOYEE     C1           D2             E4
    EMPLOYEE     C1           D2             E5 
    COMPANY      C2           -              -
    DEPARTMENT   C2           D3             -
    COMPANY      C3           -              -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SET` operator `UNION ALL` as follows:

```
SELECT 'COMPANY' AS ENTITY, 
        COMPANY_NAME, 
        '-' AS DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
        '-' AS EMPLOYEE_ID 
   FROM COMPANY C
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEPARTMENT' AS ENTITY, 
        C.COMPANY_NAME, 
        D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
        '-' AS EMPLOYEE_ID 
   FROM DEPARTMENT D 
   JOIN COMPANY C ON C.COMPANY_ID = D.COMPANY_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMPLOYEE' AS ENTITY, 
        C.COMPANY_NAME, 
        D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
        E.EMPLOYEE_ID 
  FROM DEPARTMENT D 
  JOIN COMPANY C ON C.COMPANY_ID = D.COMPANY_ID
  JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON E.DEPARTMENT_NAME = D.DEPARTMENT_NAME
ORDER BY COMPANY_NAME, 
         CASE WHEN DEPARTMENT_NAME = '-' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
         DEPARTMENT_NAME,
         CASE WHEN EMPLOYEE_ID = '-' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
         EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Comment: Above query is throwing error as "ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression"

Comment: Are you executing the same query?  I can not see any issue in the query

Comment: With this I am not getting last record for company c3.

Comment: You must be getting it as in the first query, I haven't used any filters which should select all the data from the `COMPANY` table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select
    case entity_disp
        when 1 then 'COMPANY'
        when 2 then 'DEPARTMENT'
        when 3 then 'EMPLOYEE'
    end as entity,
    company_name,
    department_name,
    employee_id
    from
    
(select
    c.company_name,
    d.department_name,
    e.employee_id,
    1 + decode(d.department_name, null, 0, 1) + decode(e.employee_id, null, 0, 1) as entity_disp
from
    company c
    left outer join department d on (d.company_name = c.company_name)
    left outer join employee  e on (e.department_name = d.department_name)
 ) c   
 order by c.entity_disp
```

Take into consideration that according yor tabel model expample it looks like that Company and Department tabels are joined based on company_name. Also Department and Employee tables are joined based on Department_name.
This is how select is implemented. If needed - rework joins with proper relational columns.